# Is there a symbol or notation for "all but"?

Tags: notation

Given four vectors $\vec x_0$, $\vec x_1$, $\vec x_2$, and $\vec x_3$, I would like to write the expression $$\det (\vec x_1, \vec x_2, \vec x_3) - \det (\vec x_0, \vec x_2, \vec x_3) + \det (\vec x_0, \vec x_1, \vec x_3)-\det (\vec x_0, \vec x_1, \vec x_2)$$ more compactly, using sigma notation.  For example, $$\sum_{k=0}^3 (-1)^k \det (\vec x_0, \vec x_1, \vec x_2, \vec x_3){\rm (but\space k)}.$$

Is there a notation for what I have written as ${\rm (but\space k)}$?

Comment: You could play with $\hat{x}_k$ similar to how Hatcher uses it in his book on Algebraic Toplogy.  See example 1B.7 in the first paragraph of page 89 of [Algebraic Toplogy (Hatcher)](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).  It doesn't quite look right for such a small example, but is in the spirit of what you are looking for.

Comment: It is worth also looking a bit further on page 105 of the same book where that notation occurs again, this time in a much closer context to what you are using with alternating signs.  While not identical to your case (*you are talking about determinants while he is talking about simplices*), it could easily be adapted if you were needing to refer to this repeatedly in a paper.  Whichever you do wind up using though, it is likely worth defining the notation used explicitly as not everyone would have been exposed to notations like this and there are surely different notations out there.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the link, but I don't like the ellipsis, it's kind of hand waving, especially when starting wit index 0 to index n which both could be meant to be excluded. By the way, I'm talking about simpleices, too. :-)

Comment: @GyroGearloose I don't think that there is any ambiguity.  When $k=0$, the notation $$\det( x_0, \dotsc, \hat{x}_k, \dotsc, x_3)$$ unambiguously expands to $$\det(\hat{x}_0, x_1, x_2, x_3). $$  I don't think that there is anything "handwavy" about this.  I think that Hatcher's notation is perfect for this task (and clicked on the title to give almost precisely the answer that JMoravitz gave).

Comment: I have seen $\vec x_0,\cdots,\vec x_{k-1},\vec x_{k+1},\cdots,\vec x_n$.

Comment: $\exists ! x, \neg P(x)$, which reads "there exists a unique thing, $x$, where $P(x)$ is not true" Just integrate that into your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write $(\vec x_j)_{j\neq k}$ for the sequence of vectors with the $k$th omitted, and hence $\det((\vec x_j)_{j\neq k})$ for the determinant you want.

Answer (score 1):

An answer and a comment:

#### Answer

There is (to my knowledge) no universally understood notation which does what you want it to do, though there are a couple of things that you could try.

1. As [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462727/is-there-a-symbol-or-notation-for-all-but#comment7118447_3462727) suggests, one can use a "hat" for the omitted element.  That is, write
   $$ \sum_{k=0}^{3} \det(x_0, \dotsc, \hat{x}_k, \dotsc, x_n). $$
   This is the notation used by Hatcher in his text [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) (see page 89).  Hatcher is widely read, so I would expect that anyone who has spent any significant time thinking about algebraic topology has probably at least *seen* this notation.
2. A similar notation would be to write
   $$\sum_{k=0}^{3} \det(x_0, \dotsc, x_{k-1}, x_{k+1}, \dotsc, x_3). $$
3. When specifying the terms of a sequence, one often uses the notation $(x_k)_{k\in \mathscr{K}}$, where $\mathscr{K}$ is some index set.  Thus one could potentially write
   $$ \sum_{k=0}^{3} \det\left( (x_j)_{j\in \{0,1,2,3\} \setminus \{k\}} \right). $$
   This notation looks quite awkward to me, but it is (I think) entirely unambiguous.
4. Similar to the above, though significantly more compactly,
   $$ \sum_{k=0}^{3} \det\left( (x_j)_{j\ne k} \right). $$
   This is a lot cleaner than (3), though might be a little ambiguous, as you would need to specify that the indices of $(x_j)$ run from $0$ to $3$—as written above, this is not obvious.  (It seems that [Especially Lime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3462810/468350) had the same idea while I was typing.)

#### Comment

Remember that the goal is clear communication.  Find a notation that you like, define it clearly in your writing, and use it consistently.  If you can't find a commonly used notation which does the job you want, you shouldn't worry about creating your own.